# Plotly: how to properly limit the row shown with a vertical scroller

Tags: plotly

I am analyzing the vaccination per hundred around the world and want to plot the country as row data and the numerical data as the column value. However, when I put the data in, lots of countries' names are hidden, with thin bars. How could I limit the rows, such as 20 rows of countries, scroll down to view more data? Thanks.

Illustration as below, currently using plotly.express.
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you add the following settings. `fig.update_yaxes(tickmode='auto', nticks=20)`

Comment: Thank you. It does give the first 20 ticks, but the bars aren't updated to "attach" to the country's name.

Comment: By the way, the latest version of Plotly does not show the scroll bar, but shows 15 countries. What version are you currently using? The latest version is 5.2.2.

Comment: Yes, the latest version was installed, but I am using express, which could be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- using this as inspiration https://community.plotly.com/t/add-scrolling-options-to-plots/9493/6
- wrap **plotly** html in a `<div style="overflow-y:scroll;height: 200px;">` so that HTML scrollbars can be used

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

# get and prepare data...
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(
    requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv").text))
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
dfp = df.dropna(subset=["continent", "total_vaccinations_per_hundred"]).loc[
    :, ["iso_code", "location", "date", "total_vaccinations_per_hundred"]
].sort_values("date").groupby("iso_code").last()


# give 15 pixels to each country for height
buffer = io.StringIO()
px.bar(dfp.sort_values("location", ascending=False),
       x="total_vaccinations_per_hundred",
       y="location",
       orientation="h"
      ).update_layout(height=len(dfp)*15).write_html(buffer, full_html=False)


# use HTML techniques for scoll bar, set heigh as required
HTML('<div style="overflow-y:scroll;height: 200px;">' + buffer.getvalue().encode().decode() + "</div>")
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a try.

Comment: Hi, I use the code and `streamlit run app.py`. The page is empty. I download the data and try again, it's the same result. Is there anything I might be wrong?

Comment: I've not used streamlit,  code above works in a jupyter environment

Comment: Oh, sorry. I use the jupyter notebook as well, but blank. I bring the code to Kaggle as public. https://www.kaggle.com/wodenwang/covid

Comment: the code I've posted works in a jupyter cell and after about 3s, creates output to cell.  have tested in safari and chrome.  your link give 404...

Comment: my problem, thank you very much. And the 404 issue was fixed as well.